# How to use a column in select statement which is not in aggregate function nor in group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

[image]

Above is the table and on the basis of which I have to answer the below question in my past interview.

**Q. The most recent order value for each customer?**

Answer which I have given in interview:

```
select customerID, ordervalue, max(orderdate)
from office
group by customerID;
```

I know since we are not using ordervalue in aggregate and nor in group by so this query will throw an error in SQL but ***I want to know how to answer this question.***

Many times in my past interviewers asked a question where I need to use a column in select statement which is not in aggregate function or nor in group by. ***So I want know in general what is a workaround for it with an example so that I can resolve these type of questions or how to answer these questions.***

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the data table as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 2):

The work around depends on what is being asked. For the requirements you have above, I think it makes sense to create `(customerid, MAX(orderdate))` pairs.

```
SELECT customerid, MAX(orderdate)
FROM office 
GROUP BY customerid;
```

Then you can use them to match the row you need from the table.

```
SELECT customerid, ordervalue, orderdate
FROM office
WHERE (customerid, orderdate) IN 
    (SELECT customerid, MAX(orderdate) 
     FROM office 
     GROUP BY customerid);
```

Note, this assumes there is only one order per customer per day. If there were more than one, you would see the most recent order(s) per customer. You could add also a `GROUP BY` on the outer query if needed.

```
SELECT customerid, MAX(ordervalue), orderdate
FROM office AS tt
WHERE (customerid, orderdate) IN 
    (SELECT customerid, MAX(orderdate) 
     FROM office
     GROUP BY customerid)
GROUP BY customerid, orderdate;
```

If the non-aggregate column you need in the `SELECT` is functionally dependent on the column in the `GROUP BY`, you can add a subquery in the `SELECT`.

We can extend your example by adding a name column, where the name of different customers could be the same. If you wanted name instead of ordervalue, just match the `customerid` of the outer query to get `name`.

```
SELECT customerid, 
  (SELECT name FROM office WHERE customerid=o.customerid LIMIT 1) AS name,
  MAX(orderdate)
FROM office AS o
GROUP BY customerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the task as follows: Aggregate all rows to get one result line per customer, showing the maximum order date and its order value. The problem with this: you'd need an aggregate function to get the value for the maximum order date. The only DBMS I know of featuring such a function is Oracle with `KEEP FIRST/LAST`.

So look at the task from a different angle. Don't think aggregation-wise where you could count and add up values for a group and get the minimum or maximum value over all the group's rows, because after all you just want to pick single rows. (That is, pick the top 1 row per customer.) In order to pick rows, you'll use a `WHERE` clause.

One option has been shown by Steve in his answer:

```
select *
from office
where (customerid, orderdate) in 
( 
  select customerid, max(orderdate)
  from office
  group by customerid
);
```

This is a good, straight-forward approach. (Some DBMS, though, don't feature tuples with `IN` clauses.)

Another way to get the "best" row for a customer would be to pick those rows for which not exists a better row:

```
select *
from office
where not exists
( 
  select null
  from office better
  where better.customerid = office.customerid
  and better.orderdate > office.orderdate
);
```

And then there is the option to use a window function (aka analytic function) in order to get those rows. One example is to get the maximum dates along with the rows' data:

```
select customerid, ordervalue, orderdate
from
(
  select
    customerid, ordervalue, orderdate,
    max(orderdate) over (partition by customerid) as max_orderdate
  from office
)
where orderdate = max_orderdate;
```

And with `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, and `DENSE_RANK` there are window functions to assign numbers to your rows in the order you want. You number them such that the best rows get number 1 and pick them. The big advantage here: you can apply any order, deal with ties and not only get the top 1, but the top n rows.

```
select customerid, ordervalue, orderdate
from
(
  select
    customerid, ordervalue, orderdate,
    row_number() over (partition by customerid order by orderdate desc) as rn
  from office
)
where rn = 1;
```